# How would you find the height of objects given an image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, photogrammetry

This isn't exactly a programming question exactly. I just want to know what your approach would be to a common problem in Digital image processing.

Let's say you have an image of a few trees in say jpg format. How would you go about finding the heights of each of these trees? The photo is the only input you have.

I want to know the approaches you have not to code. So it doesn't matter if your answers are vague, or non DIP-ish.

Small correction : 
The height need not be the actual height of the tree. The height can be taken to any scale. But should be consistent to all objects in the pic.

Comment: If the photo is the only input you have, it can't be done.  Consider a bonsai tree photographed from a close distance, versus a full-sized tree photographed from further away....

Comment: If you get the date and location from the exif then all you need to do is some shadow detection. Then you'll have everything to calculate the height by using the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @Jim Lewis-- does the photo have associated metadata, like lens information and focal length?  Because if you know the distance to the trees from that, and the pixel-to-inches(or feet, or whatever), then it's a matter of separating the trees from background.

Comment: basically you need to know the exact height of an object within the image.  Then from there you can use that exact height as a comparison to the trees.

Comment: You need something in the photo that you can get the size to fairly accurately. I'm not sure of the math, but there's an iPhone app that uses a credit card in the picture to estimate the sizes of objects in the scene. Maybe something like that will help you...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  What you are describing has an entire industry around it, called [**Photogrammetry**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry)

Comment: I don't see where that comes even close to an answer im afraid. it is a nice link though...

Comment: no I didn't. merely a link to a wikipedia article is not an answer

Answer (score 5):

It is simple to find the size of an object from images using Photogrammetry.
Photogrammetry is the science of making measurements from photographs.
For this we need to know two things,

- the distance between the camera and the image plane(distance from camera to object).
- Focal-length(in mm and pixels per mm) or physical size of the image sensor.

Following are the steps:

***Calibrate the Camera***

Use openCV to calibrate the camera.You can use the OpenCV calibrate.py tool and the Chessboard pattern PNG provided in the source code to generate a calibration matrix. Camera calibration is done to find the camera parameters. I took about  a dozen of photos of the chessboard photos from many angles as I could with my webcam (to calibrate my webcam). For more details check [openCV camera calibration](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html).

We will get f_x,f_y,c_x,c_y from calibration matrix.

Checking the details of the photos you took, you will find the native resolution of the photos(heightXwidth) and in their [EXIF headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) you can find the focal length value(f). These items may vary depending on your camera.

***Pixels per millimeter***

We need to know the pixels per millimeter(px/mm) on the image sensor.

**f_x=f*m_x**

**f_y=f*m_y**

Since we have two of the variables for each formula we can solve for m_x and m_y.I just averaged f_x and f_y to get f_xy.

**m=f_xy/focal_length_of_camera**

***Insert the image***

Insert your image from which you need to find the actual size of image. You should know the distance between object and camera. Find the dimension of the image (height1Xwidth1)

***Find the Object size in pixels***

Determine the size of object in pixels. I simply use distance formula to find length of a selected line. You can adopt any other method.

***Convert px/mm in the lower resolution***

**pxpermm_in_lower_resolution = (width1*m)/width**

***Size of object in the image sensor***

**size_of_object_in_image_sensor = object_size_in_pixels/(pxpermm_in_lower_resolution)**

***Actual size of object***

The actual size of object can be found with the above data as,

**real_size = (dist*size_of_object_in_image_sensor)/focal_length**

Answer (score 4):

There is a fair amount of computer vision research in this area.  Assuming you don't know the camera constraints, you'll have to make assumptions about the scene and camera to determine the heights up to a scale factor.  Note that without camera constraints or a reference height in the image it is impossible to tell the difference between a tall tree photographed from a distance or a short tree photographed up close.  A great start is the [Single View Metrology](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67279/criminisi_dagm2002.pdf) work by Criminisi.

Comment: thanks for that. But see i'm not looking for exact height or anything. I just want relative heights of objects. Taken relative to anything0you wish. How do i measure it in a pic?

Comment: Did you look at the document I referenced?  It has that exact application.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they're all the same distance away, all to scale, you'd want to find a single unit of measurement you can guarantee. For example, if there's a person in the photo, again, same scale, and you know they're exactly 6 feet tall, you use that as your measure. You then take that, and count how many stacked make the tree. For example, if you need 3.5 of this person, then:

```
3.5 * 6 = 21
```

gives you a 21 foot tall tree.

Without a single point of reference for everything, or if they're all on different scales, you would need a lot more information than you could easily get without having been there.

Answer (score 0):

I would rely on an object of known dimensions to be present in the picture. For instance, a man.

Or perhaps, we could use the EXIF data to reverse engineer the size of the object based on the camera's sensor dimensions, the lens and the focal length used. This again depends on the angle. We should be getting most accurate results when the camera has been held perpendicular to the subject.

Comment: A man is not of known dimensions.  Unless you know he's standing and his standing height.

Comment: sounds good. But how would you isolate each object? the object from the background etc.

Answer (score -4):

If your image is 3*3 and you want to find out the size of image (i.e 3x3..so 3x3 = 9) now we have 8 pixels starting from 0 up to 8. So 9/8=(___)kb.

If you want to find the size of image in MB, like doing above example, just do like that (9/8)/(1024)=(----)MB..

So you will get the result in Mb.