# Measure the real size of an object from an unknown picture

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

What is the approach to measure the real size (length, height and width) of an object from an image while I don't know the focal length or the object distance (I don't know the origin of the image, i.e. any technical details of the lens or the camera)?

Comment: I'm sorry that's not possible. You would need to know the camera parameters. Think about it for a minute.  Take an object and a camera and take a picture.  Then, take two more images - One where the distance between the object and camera are the same while you zoom in, and another where the zoom settings stay the same, but you move the camera.  Without the focal length and other camera parameters, it would be completely ambiguous to determine what the true size of the object is, as you could configure and orient your camera in multiple positions to allow it to image in the same fashion.

Comment: This seems to address the problem quite well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940140/how-to-get-the-real-life-size-of-an-object-from-an-image-when-not-knowing-the-d?rq=1