# Find the real sizes of a rectangle drawn into an image

Tags: opencv, math, image-processing, computer-vision, projection

I can't find **anywhere** a solution to this problem, so I'm asking here hoping someone has the solution.

## **The problem is the following:**

given an image is it possible to find the *"real sizes"*, intended as the projection onto the horizontal plane of the road, of a rectangle drawn in an image?

I have *probably* any information needed to solve this problem:

- focal of the camera in millimetres mm
- height of the camera compared to the road surface in cm
- inclination camera compared to the road surface in °
- sensor size in inches
- sizes of the image in px
- sizes of the rectangle in px
- position of the rectangle compared to the image in px retrieved by using openCV

However I miss the formulas to even start writing down the code.

Here 2 screenshots taken from Google. In both of them the rectangle is the same size, it has been only moved upward which creates another big issue: **Perspective**.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

By looking around noone seems to even mention the projection onto the horizontal plane neither perspective. Honestly I can't even figure out where to start, I've never dealt with something like this before.
If I didn't make everything clear, don't hesitate asking.

**EDIT 1:**
Here there are 2 pictures for better understanding the problem.

- The first one as a context image:

[image: Context]

- The second one as a visual example from https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html of what is the point of all of
  this (sorry for the low quality level). The blue indicates the road, while the orange rectangle is the projection of the red one on the road plane:

[image: Visual example]

Comment: Using the height and inclination of the camera, you should know where its optical center is and where camera is facing. Assume the point on ground right below camera to be origin of the world with road being the ground plane. Generate extrinsic matrix for the camera using this.

Comment: Using the extrinsic and intrinsic matrix of the camera, you should be able to project two optical rays from camera center towards the pixel of lane on the image plane. Keep shooting the ray forward until it reaches the ground plane.  When these rays reaches the ground floor, you will know the real location of the lane in the world coordinate system.

Comment: And if you couldn't find anything about this, you might have simply been searching for the wrong terms. For instance, [How to get the real life size of an object from an image, when not knowing the distance between object and the camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940140/how-to-get-the-real-life-size-of-an-object-from-an-image-when-not-knowing-the-d) covers exactly this problem. It doesn't _solve_ it for you, but it gives you the information necessary to continue your own (re)searching into the topic.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that was the formula I kept finding but wasn't, I suppose, related. For instance, it gives information about the distance of an object know it's real dimension, wether height or weight.
In my case, and that's the problem noone seems to cover, the object is laying on  the ground. That's why I necessarily had to find the position of the rectangle relative to the big image.
I've been searching for almost a month, I think I'm missing something but I don't really know what

Comment: @saurabheights could you please send links to docs related to this topic? I'd appreciate it. I'm really new to CV but at the same tame I don't want to bother others too much

Comment: yeah, take a course in CV. specifically the geometry part of it, starting from the camera obscura. or dive into the practical side. -- your bullet points should be enough to figure this out. you just need the equations, as you say. -- you need an estimation of the ground plane. usually, that's done with a homography. do they specify the length of the lane marks in your country? do the road painters stick to the specs?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the lenght varies between 12 to 25 based on the road type, but in some road they are not even present or they're just very discolored or damaged. I'm adding another actual example to better undersand the context.
As saurabheights suggested in the first comment I found this doc which _I think_ covers the topic: [https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html)

Comment: @INotDxvid I was going to share the same url. Glad you already found it. Just remember,  you need to cover pinhole camera model, intrinsic and extrinsic matrix to correctly calculate this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem essentially boils down to “what is the position on the ground that corresponds to any given pixel coordinate position” because once you have that, determining ground positions for four corners of a quadrilateral is easy.

If you assume a pinhole camera, you have a direct ray of light from a point on the ground through the pinhole to the sensor. So the most important part is to embed your sensor coordinate system correctly into 3d space.

1. Start with a rectangle of the known pixel dimensions of the sensor.
2. Scale it to the physical dimensions of the sensor. So the scale factor is essentially the inverse of pixel density.
3. Shift it so that the center of the sensor is at the origin. We assume the optical axis of the camera is through the center.
4. Offset it by the physical focal length (not the 35mm equivalent focal length) perpendicular to the sensor plane. Now the sensor is facing the pinhole at the right distance.
5. Rotate to the known inclination of the camera.
6. Model the ground as a horizontal plane with the distance to the origin matching the height of the camera.

Steps 1 through 5 should allow you to take (x, y) positions in the resulting image and turn them into 3d positions of the corresponding point on the correctly positioned sensor. Any multiple of that 3d vector is a point on the line spanned by the point on the sensor and the pinhole. Pick the multiple that also lies in the ground plane, i.e. has the one non-zero coordinate match that of the ground. It is your position on the ground.

All of this will take care of perspective by having different positions in the image correspond to different positions on the ground so that the same pixel distance on the sensor doesn't correspond to equal distances on the ground.

OpenCV might have some tools to help with all of this, but understanding how to correctly use those tools might be harder than multiplying 4 matrices to combine the basic transformations I outlined above. If you can't assume the camera to act like a pinhole camera, things become a lot more complicated, though.

Related topics: see [Finding the transform matrix from 4 projected points](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) for how to compute the matrix if instead of camera parameters you have 4 matching points, and see [How to calculate true lengths from perspective projection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217092/35416) if instead of camera parameters you know the size of a visible object in the plane.